# EmailMessage.RelatedToId not valid for Lead in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, emailmessage

My process runs 3 minutes after lead creation. It sends an email to the lead and logs the message in Email Message.

Here's the error...

> Error Occurred: This error occurred when the flow tried to create
>   records: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION: Related To ID: id value of
>   incorrect type: 00Q0P00000xqeEwUAI.

Here's the process action...
[image]

When I look it up, the Lead is valid and not deleted.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated the object to Allow Activities and it worked. This happened because on EmailMessage's RelatedTo field, the object in question was not listed. By Allowing Activities, that object gets placed as a valid value for RelatedTo.

Comment: How did you update the Lead object to allow activities. Could you please let me know?

Comment: Hi Alex, yes, just navigate to the SObject and in Details, click Edit. When you scroll to the bottom, you will see a section called Optional Features, and then a checkbox called Allow Activities. Hope that helps.